# How to make the Container take the minimal width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints, navigationbar

I am trying to make a custom `BottomNavigationBar` in `Flutter`, and here is the code.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 25),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 30, 32),
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.home_filled),
              Text("Home"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
        child: Icon(Icons.document_scanner, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
        child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This code outcomes the following result, where the `Container`'s width matches its parent's width, maintaining the `margin` and `padding`. The inner `Row` is supposed to take all available space.

[image: Navigation Bar Container]

### Expectation

I expect the `Container` to be the smallest. It should not take all available width, but it should fit-wrap all its contents. There should not be spaces between the items.

The Expanded widget is not a problem here. I have also tried setting the inner `Row`'s `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` but no luck. Tell me if my any portion of my question couldn't be understood.

After Removing the Expanded Widget:

[image: Without Expanded widget]

Expected:

[image: No space between items]

Comment: I didn't get your issue, could you include a ui image of what you try to acheive?

Comment: I've added but it's showing broken.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @AshrafulAlamShakil

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `Expanded` and wrap your `bottomNavigationBar` with `align` like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Align( // <-- add this
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // <-- add this
    heightFactor: 1, // <-- add this
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 25),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 30, 32),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container( // <-- change this
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                Text("Home"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
            child: Icon(Icons.document_scanner, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
            child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**Note**: if you need more padding between items you can change middle item's padding.

[image: Result]

Comment: @AshrafulAlamShakil is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) says:

> A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the
> child fills the available space.

`Expanded` will fill up the available space, so you need to remove it or try the following code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 25),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 30, 32),
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.home_filled),
              Text("Home"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: Icon(Icons.document_scanner, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello there, In the last part of my question I have also added that removing the `Expanded` widget does not solve the problem. You can see the screenshot attached.

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: The black Container which is the root Container, should not take whole horizontal space. Rather it should hug its contents. In the last screenshot, there should not be the spaces between the items.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code wrap your other widget with [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or Remove *Container of the 1st Home widget*

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 25),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 30, 32),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                  Text("Home"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: Icon(Icons.document_scanner, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `Spacer()` widget in between your `Row` children and it works like you want to:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 25),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 30, 32),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                    Text("Home"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(), //just add these
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: Icon(Icons.document_scanner, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Spacer(), //in your existing code
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
              child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```